# Adding a c-wire to a Goodman A30-10C for smart thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

[image][image]Looking for a little help installing a c-wire on my Goodman A30-10C so I can run a new Sensi smart thermostat.

I currently don’t have a c-wire running to the thermostat, and don’t really know where to start. From what I’ve read it seems pretty easy to do, but don’t want to mess anything up.

My unit is an older unit 01/1996 but works perfectly. I’d appreciate any help or guidance I can get.

[image]
<sup>Click any image to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how many wires in the thermostat controller cable go out. I think i see 4 or ?

Comment: One picture missing, from the thermostat whirring please provide

Comment: take another phot of the wiring diagram, but this time get it  in focus.

Comment: The wiring diagram (image vPvfA.jpg) shows one connection of the control transformer (image 61Lun.jpg) is grounded, that transformer connection is the C. A better image of the label on the transformer would help with complete details, it may be marked 0v.

Comment: The thermostat currently has 4 wires running to it, removed it off the call and no extra wires. I've added a better picture of the wiring diagram and the thermostat. I'll have to get a better picture of the transformer once I get home this afternoon.

Comment: If you still have the original transformer (and it appears there may be modifications) you will need to tap the wire connected to terminal 5.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease just posted a better picture of the transformer

Comment: @Corey -- is there an extra wire available in your thermostat cable?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not that I had noticed. I do have some new 18/5 cable on a roll tho.

Comment: @Corey -- where does the other cable go in your photo of the thermostat cable termination in the air handler?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't clearly see the markings on the transformer or able to trace the wires from image to image.

But the Ov "C" source is one of the two wires on the bottom of the transformer. If you trace those two wires one will connect to a wire that connects to the "R" on the stat, that is the +24v. The other terminal is the Ov terminal. You may have to cut the wire that is attached to the terminal and use a wire connector if tapping into another existing splice is not an option.

Comment: The lighter pink wire coming from transformer is running to the R wire on the thermostat. The purple and red are running to the sequencer’s from the transformer, and the black is running to what looks like a ground in the unit.

Comment: The 0v side of the transformer should be grounded, as the wiring diagram shows. That confirms that it is the wire you need.

Comment: Just so I don’t screw anything up, what color wire would I be tapping into? Sorry if I’m not understanding.